# show $ -\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^3}p\frac{\partial f(p,t)}{\partial p}=3F$

Tags: integration, physics

Hi I am stuck with an integral problem trying to show  $$ -\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^3}p\frac{\partial f(p,t)}{\partial p}=3F$$ where $F=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^{3}pf(p,t)$ I have read in many books that simply integrated by parts to get the solution, but I just dont get it can anyone help?

Comment: What is the variable of integration: $p$ or $t$? Is $p$ a function of $t$, or an independent variable? Does $d^3p$ mean the constant $d^3$ times $p$, or some sort of third derivative? The problem is not clear enough at the moment.

Comment: Could you precise what $g$ and $d$ are? Especially this $d^3p$...

Answer (score 16):

Let me translate the physics type of notation back to calculus: assume your configuration space is just $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $p = \langle x,y,z\rangle $ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, also the function $f$ is smooth and the product with $x$, $y$,or $z$ vanishes when $\|p\| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\to \infty$. Since there is no time here we treat $t$ as a constant. Then the integral can be rewritten in mathematical rigor to avoid vagueness:
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^3}p\frac{\partial f(p,t)}{\partial p} &= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \nabla_p f\cdot p \,dxdydz
\\
&= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \langle \partial_x f, \partial_y f, \partial_z f \rangle\cdot \langle x,y,z\rangle \,dxdydz
\\
&= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} (x \, \partial_x f + y\,  \partial_y + z\, \partial_z f)\,dxdydz
\end{aligned}
$$
Split the integrands into three parts:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} (x\, \partial_x f + y \, \partial_y + z\, \partial_z f)\,dxdydz
\\
=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} x \partial_x f\,dx)dydz
+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} y \partial_y f\,dy)dxdz + \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} z \partial_z f\,dz)dxdy
\end{aligned} 
$$
For each integral: let $u= x$, $dv = \partial_x f\,dx$, then by integral by parts formula $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^1}u dv = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^1}v du$, if $uv$ goes to zero at infinity.
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} x \partial_x f\,dx = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} f\,dx
$$
Hence:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} x \partial_x f\,dx)dydz = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} f\,dx dydz
$$
for we assumed $xf(x,y,z,t) \to 0$ when $x\to \infty$. Do the same thing for other two terms:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} (x\, \partial_x f + y \, \partial_y + z\, \partial_z f)\,dxdydz = -3\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} f\,dx dydz
$$
Therefore:
$$
-\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^3}p\frac{\partial f(p,t)}{\partial p} = \frac{3}{(2\pi)^3} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}f\,dx dydz = \frac{3}{(2\pi)^3} \int f(p,t) \,d^3p = 3F.
$$
Also the last remark is that: the configuration space needs not to be $\mathbb{R}^3$, it may be a manifold, $p$ is a tangent vector, momentum is cotangent. And the formula is still valid.

Comment: I like your "translation." +1

Comment: Clear answer(+1). Why do physicists use cryptic notations? :-)

Comment: @vesszabo I am guessing they don't want to specify which space they are integrating in, for you could have momentum space or position space, which corresponds to frequency variable or spacial variable. Or rather a many-particle system, or on a manifold, also based on my experience of taking a QM course in physics department, physicists somewhat tend to think notations in math are redundant in the sense that they are too rigorous to represent a large class of similar things. And $d^3 p = dp_1 dp_2 dp_3$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} = \nabla_p f$ just seem to be their convention.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I see. Many thanks.